# How to do groupby summary statistics in Pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Currently, I'm doing groupby summary statistics in Pyspark, the pandas version is avaliable as below

```
import pandas as pd

packetmonthly=packet.groupby(['year','month','customer_id']).apply(lambda s: pd.Series({ 
    "packet_sum": s.amount.sum(),
    "packet_min": s.amount.min(),
    "packet_max": s.amount.max(),
    "packet_avg": s.amount.mean()
})).reset_index()
```

How to do it in Pyspark?

Comment: I suggest you to provide a small sample dataset (in pandas is fine) along with the desired output

Comment: Also add your try to solving the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the groupBy() and agg() functions for this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max as pyspark_max, min as pyspark_min, sum as pyspark_sum, avg


df = df \
    .groupBy('year', 'month', 'customer_id') \
    .agg(pyspark_min('amount').alias('packet_min'),
         pyspark_max('amount').alias('packet_max'),
         avg('amount').alias('packet_avg'),
         pyspark_sum('amount').alias('packet_sum'))
```

Comment: Why you need doing alias?

Comment: Otherwise pyspark names those columns like this ```min(amount)```, ```max(amount)``` etc.

Comment: I want to add to this question - I am doing something similar, but I want to get the percentiles of a few columns with a group by. Some psuedo code for what I am looking for is something like: spark_DF.groupBy('account_type').summary(5%, 10%, 15%..., 95%, 100%).show()

Comment: @GenDemo I have the exact same question as you, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @bernando_vialli nope - I ended up doing it in pandas. The problem I had, is that spark has percentile function, but it approximates the answer. So you dont get an accurate number and it could change everytime you run it - this was not sufficient for me. So pandas it is.